# logical partitions missing from /dev

Tags: linux, partition

A little detail for everyone.  I'm working with OracleVM Manager.  I have been using a 700GB drive noted in Linux as /dev/xvdc.  xvdc does have several partitions which I'll list below.  I expanded the drive to 1TB and rebooted the server and fdisk now notices the drive is larger.  (Yes, I know this should be LVM, but I have yet to convince the organization to make the move.)

Here is xvdc prior to doing anything.

```
ls -la /dev/xvdc*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 32 Aug  2 08:24 /dev/xvdc
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 33 Aug  1 18:45 /dev/xvdc1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 42 Aug  1 18:45 /dev/xvdc10
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 43 Aug  1 18:45 /dev/xvdc11
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 44 Aug  1 18:45 /dev/xvdc12
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 45 Aug  1 18:45 /dev/xvdc13
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 46 Aug  1 18:45 /dev/xvdc14
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 47 Aug  1 18:45 /dev/xvdc15
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 34 Aug  1 18:45 /dev/xvdc2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 37 Aug  1 18:45 /dev/xvdc5
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 38 Aug  1 18:45 /dev/xvdc6
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 39 Aug  1 18:45 /dev/xvdc7
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 40 Aug  1 18:45 /dev/xvdc8
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 41 Aug  1 18:45 /dev/xvdc9
```

Used fdisk to make xvdc16-21

```
Disk /dev/xvdc: 1012.5 GB, 1012538540032 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 123100 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000eace1

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvdc1               1        6528    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc2            6529      122868   934499136    5  Extended
/dev/xvdc5            6529       13056    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc6           13057       19584    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc7           19585       26112    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc8           26113       32640    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc9           32641       39168    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc10          39169       45696    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc11          45697       52224    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc12          52225       58752    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc13          58753       65280    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc14          65281       71808    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc15          71809       78336    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc16          78337       84864    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc17          84865       91392    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc18          91393       97920    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc19          97921      104448    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc20         104449      110976    52436128+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc21         110977      117504    52436128+  83  Linux
```

Used partprobe to read in the new partitions

```
partprobe -s /dev/xvdc
/dev/xvdc: msdos partitions 1 2 <5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21>
```

Checked to logs to ensure the change took place.  However, it did not.

```
cat /var/log/messages | grep -i xvdc
Aug  1 10:42:51 hgpsfsdevdb kernel: xvdc: xvdc1 xvdc2 < xvdc5 xvdc6 xvdc7 xvdc8 xvdc9 xvdc10 xvdc11 xvdc12 xvdc13 xvdc14 xvdc15 >
```

At this point I ran kpart to ensure the partitions could be read.

```
kpartx /dev/xvdc
xvdc1 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 63
xvdc2 : 0 2 /dev/xvdc 104872320
xvdc5 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 104872383
xvdc6 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 209744703
xvdc7 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 314617023
xvdc8 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 419489343
xvdc9 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 524361663
xvdc10 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 629233983
xvdc11 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 734106303
xvdc12 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 838978623
xvdc13 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 943850943
xvdc14 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 1048723263
xvdc15 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 1153595583
xvdc16 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 1258467903
xvdc17 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 1363340223
xvdc18 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 1468212543
xvdc19 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 1573084863
xvdc20 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 1677957183
xvdc21 : 0 104872257 /dev/xvdc 1782829503
```

Tried one last reboot and repeated the steps above with no change.

What am i missing?  Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a limitation of 15 partitions, some disk types under Linux supported up to 63 but I believe it's been set to 15 for all types. You're expecting `/dev/xvdc16` to have major number 202 and minor number 48, etc. but that's going to be `/dev/xvdd`, `/dev/xvdd1` etc. for the whole disk and 15 partitions belonging to next virtual disk.

As you've already alluded to, you'll have better luck using LVM if you need many filesystems on the same physical disk.

Comment: Confirmed via Oracle support.  Kernel only supports 15 partitions.